# AJAX returning result, but giving 500 server error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Okay so I have a site here

It's running off of CubeCart and I have run into a little issue with some weird AJAX

To see the error, please

---

1. gcollective.com.au/register.html

register an account (the error only exists when logged in... a clue?)

2. http://gcollective.com.au/beef-order-form.html

You need to add an item from this order form to the cart, so just go here and scroll to the bottom after the page loads and then add it to your cart. The reason for this is because the ajax error only shows up if you have something added to your cart AND you are signed in.

3. http://gcollective.com.au/bimonthly-order-form.html

This is where the main issue is and it's a good example although it DOES happen in more places.

Once on this page, click the "Chilled Products" category on the right side of the page. It should just end up continually loading.

---

The issue is that for SOME reason it's returning a 500 internal service error even though the AJAX is getting an HTML response from the server that has no errors in it as you can tell from accessing the AJAX called page directly through your console...

ANY ideas at all?????? I can provide more info if required!

Thanks

B

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: The 500 error indicates a problem on your server. You need to investigate the cause of that problem.

Comment: Please provide us with the prompted error rather than having us register somewhere.

Comment: Simply just ask your hosting provide about this error